# Grouping data with specified max data

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good day, I'm sorry with my title. Ok, For an example i have this data

```
OutletAsal  OutletTujuan    remark  ExternalDocNo   ItemCode    Qty
K-AEON        K-AR4         DUS 20  CLOSING       WFS170402776  2
K-AEON        K-AR4         DUS 20  CLOSING       WFS170402758  1
K-AEON        K-AR4         DUS 20  CLOSING       WFS170402790  1
K-AEON        K-AR4         DUS 20  CLOSING       WFS170502796  2
K-AEON        K-AR4         DUS 20  CLOSING       WHS170400011  1
K-AEON        K-AR4         DUS 20  CLOSING       WHS170400015  1
K-AEON        K-AR4         DUS 21  CLOSING       WHS170400015  1
```

So, i want to achieve this (Grouping OutletAsal,OutletTujuan,Remark,ExtrnalDocNo Maximum 5 records, if there is 6 records then it will make 2 headers)

```
#Header
OutletAsal  OutletTujuan    remark  ExternalDocNo HeaderID
K-AEON        K-AR4         DUS 20  CLOSING         1
K-AEON        K-AR4         DUS 20  CLOSING         2
K-AEON        K-AR4         DUS 21  CLOSING         3

#detail
     ItemCode     Qty  HeaderID
    WFS170402776   2     1
    WFS170402758   1     1
    WFS170402790   1     1
    WFS170502796   2     1
    WHS170400011   1     1
    WHS170400015   1     2
    WHS170400015   1     3
```

For now i have this query for `header` part

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(OutletAsal)) OutletAsal,LTRIM(RTRIM(OutletTujuan)) OutletTujuan,Remark,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY OutletAsal,OutletTujuan,Remark ASC) AS Urut
into #tempgroup
FROM ImportCsvDO
GROUP BY OutletAsal ,OutletTujuan , Remark ,ExternalDocNo
```

with my query above i get this and this is not like i expected (Please check above)

```
OutletAsal  OutletTujuan    Remark  Urut
K-AEON       K-AR4           DUS 20 1
K-AEON       K-AR4           DUS 21 2
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Which of the six source records are those two `remark = DUS 20` meant to represent? I see no clue here as to how you decide to get three records out of six.

Comment: When i simply group with `GROUP BY OutletAsal ,OutletTujuan , Remark ,ExternalDocNo` without selecting ItemCode amd Qty it will create 1 record right ?  becase it has 6 records i want to make it to two records. the first record has 5 and the second record has 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `modulo (%)` in SQl like this

```
;with temp AS
(
    SELECT *,
         row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY OutletAsal ,OutletTujuan , Remark ,ExternalDocNo ORDER BY ic.Id) AS Rn
    FROM ImportCsvDO ic
)
SELECT  OutletAsal,
       OutletTujuan,
       Remark,
       ExternalDocNo,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY OutletAsal,OutletTujuan,Remark ASC) AS HeaderId,
       t.Rn as GroupHeaderId 
FROM temp t
WHERE t.Rn % 5 = 1
```

And detail table (assuming that you have header table)

```
;with temp AS
(
    SELECT *,
         row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY OutletAsal ,OutletTujuan , Remark ,ExternalDocNo ORDER BY ic.Id) AS Rn
    FROM @SampleData ic
)
SELECT t.ItemCode,
      Qty,       
      ht.HeaderId AS HeaderID
FROM temp t
INNER JOIN @HeaderTable ht ON     t.OutletAsal = ht.OutletAsal
                          AND t.OutletTujuan = ht.OutletTujuan
                          AND t.Remark = ht.remark
                          AND t.ExternalDocNo = ht.ExternalDocNo
                          AND (t.Rn - 1) / 5 = (ht.GroupHeaderId - 1) / 5
```

See my demo here

http://rextester.com/AMDK48783

Comment: So, is it possible to  get the detail part ? ItemCode and Qty

Comment: my bad, i accidentally delete `/5`

Comment: Please explain what is this for ? `1 + (row_number() 
       OVER(PARTITION BY OutletAsal ,OutletTujuan , Remark ,ExternalDocNo ORDER BY ic.Id) - 1` and It the detail part. the `header_Id` are 1-2-1